# How to push data/records from ConsumeFromTopicOperator to XCom

Tags: python, apache-kafka, airflow

Say, i have an airflow DAG, where im trying to consume (ConsumeFromTopicOperator using https://github.com/astronomer/airflow-provider-kafka ) data from kafka topic and pass those to pythonOperator. My process_message function called pythonOperator does not print anything for the variable `message`. Anyway, what im doing wrong ?

```py
dag = DAG(dag_id='Stream_Employee_Data_Loader',
          default_args=default_args,
          catchup=False,
          schedule_interval=None)

def process_message(ti, **context):
    message = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='consume_records', key='message')
    # Process the message or perform any required transformations
    print(message)
    
    ti.xcom_push(key='processed_data', value=processed_data)

retrieve_data_task = PythonOperator(
         task_id='retrieve_data',
         python_callable=process_message,
         provide_context=True,
         do_xcom_push=True,
         dag=dag
     )


def consumer_function(messages, prefix=None):
    consumer_logger.info("starting consumer function")
    consumer_logger.info(f"Messages {messages}")
    for message in messages:
        consumer_logger.info(
            f"{prefix} {message.topic()} @ {message.offset()}; Message {message.value().decode('utf-8')}"
        )
    return
    

consume_task = ConsumeFromTopicOperator(
        task_id='consume_records',
        topics=[kafka_topic],
        apply_function_batch=functools.partial(
            consumer_function, prefix="consumed:::"
        ),
        consumer_config={
            "bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
            "group.id": "kafka_connection",
            "enable.auto.commit": False,
            "auto.offset.reset": "beginning",
        },
        commit_cadence="end_of_batch",
        max_messages=10,
        max_batch_size=2,
        do_xcom_push=True,
        dag=dag
    )

consume_task >> retrieve_data_task
```

AwaitFromKafkaTopic operator does work, but only captures 1 record from the topic. which is not what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put your processing logic in the consume loop directly ? That's the intended application of the operator.